# Plotly Time series forecasting in R - modify default x axis and y axis range

Tags: r, plotly, forecasting

I have a query on Time series forecasting with plotly. I have built a forecasting chart however few things needs to be changed but its not working for me. Please find the attachment for details and kindly let me know the correction or suggestion for R code.

**Query:**

1. currently X Axis is showing 2,016.5, 2017 , 2017.5 , etc however I want it to show **yearmonth** like 2016.04,2014,05,etc.
   Please be informed **yearmonth** is a field in data, please refer attached data
2. currently Y Axis is showing lables with the difference of 50 K , however I want it to show as 5 K, 10K,15K, etc.

Below is R code used :

```
library(forecast)
library(plotly)
ord <- order(ds$`Calendar Year-DISPLAY_KEY`,ds$`Calendar Month-DISPLAY_KEY`)
sds <- ds[ord,]
firstRec <- sds[1,]
mn <- as.numeric(firstRec$'Calendar Month-DISPLAY_KEY')    
yr <- as.numeric(as.character(firstRec$'Calendar Year-DISPLAY_KEY'))
tm <- ts(data = sds$Calc_Best_DSO , start= c(yr,mn) ,frequency = 12)
plot(tm)
tm[is.na(tm)] <-0

fit <- ets(tm)
fore <- forecast(fit, h = 3, level = c(80, 95))

plot_ly() %>%
  add_lines(x = time(tm), y = tm,hoverinfo = "text",
            color = I("black"), name = "observed",text= paste("Month: ",sds$`Calendar Month-DISPLAY_KEY`,
                    "<br>","Year: ",sds$`Calendar Year-DISPLAY_KEY`,
                   "<br>","DSO: ",sds$Calc_Best_DSO)) %>%
  add_ribbons(x = time(fore$mean), ymin = fore$lower[, 2], ymax = fore$upper[, 2],
              color = I("gray95"), name = "95% confidence") %>%
  add_ribbons(x = time(fore$mean), ymin = fore$lower[, 1], ymax = fore$upper[, 1],
              color = I("gray80"), name = "80% confidence") %>%
  add_lines(x = time(fore$mean), y = fore$mean, color = I("blue"), name = "prediction")
```

**Below is sample data:**

```
Month,Year,YearMonth,Population
1,2017,201701,100
1,2018,201801,300
2,2018,201802,310
3,2018,201803,320
4,2018,201804,330
2,2017,201702,200
3,2017,201703,300
4,2017,201704,400
5,2017,201705,500
6,2017,201706,600
7,2017,201707,700
8,2017,201708,800
9,2017,201709,900
10,2017,201710,1000
11,2017,201711,1100
12,2017,201712,1200
```

[image: Data]

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to format your dates as `R` `date`s. That would help with formatting.

```
library(plotly)
x <- read.table(
  text = 'Month,Year,YearMonth,Population
1,2017,201701,100
  1,2018,201801,300
  2,2018,201802,310
  3,2018,201803,320
  4,2018,201804,330
  2,2017,201702,200
  3,2017,201703,300
  4,2017,201704,400
  5,2017,201705,500
  6,2017,201706,600
  7,2017,201707,700
  8,2017,201708,800
  9,2017,201709,900
  10,2017,201710,1000
  11,2017,201711,1100
  12,2017,201712,1200', 
  header = TRUE, sep = ','
)
x$YearMonth <- as.Date(paste0(x$YearMonth, '01'), format = '%Y%m%d') # Formatting as dates
x$Population <- x$Population * 100 # Scaling population to show large numbers
x <- x[with(x, order(YearMonth)), ] # Sorting by date
p <- plot_ly(
  data = x, x = ~YearMonth, y = ~Population, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines'
) %>% layout(
  xaxis = list(tickformat = '%Y.%m'), # This formatting option should help with your desired format
  yaxis = list(tick0 = min(x$Population), dtick = 5000, tickformat = '.2s') # Be sure to include min for tick0
)
p
```

This results in the following graph - 
[image]

Comment: Glad to help! Would you consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer if you think it solved your problem?

Comment: Ameya I marked it as correct answer. One more info needed. My original post has forecasting code also. How to reuse forecasting code in this .

Comment: You will need to convert `time(ts)` to  an `R` `date` forrmat. That is tricky in base `R`. You can try `zoo::as.Date.yearmon` to extract time from `ts` objects.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to customize your axis in plotly is to set a variable with the options you want.

For the x-axis, it would look similar to the code below.

```
    a <- list(
       autotick = FALSE,
       tick0 = 0,
       dtick = 1)
```

This will only show ticks on the x-axis every interval of 1. I realize this was not what you were asking. Using dtick = .01, will make the x-axis hard to read.

For the y-axis, it would look similar to the code below.

```
   b <- list(
      autotick = FALSE,
      tick0 = 0,
      dtick = 5000) #for 5k intervals
```

Now you must simply input these into your plotly code. Here is an example.

```
    plot_ly()%>%
      add_lines(x = time(tm) y = tm, hoverinfo = text, color = I("black"), name = "Observed") %>%
      layout(xaxis = a, yaxis = b)
```

This should work. All you will need to do is define a and b, then simply add the layout to your current plotly code.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Hi M. Wickers, Thanks for your response. Y axis worked perfectly as expected. However, XAxis is not working. After your code its showing 2017 and 2018. I need to show as per my YearMonth Feild. Please find the attachment from my question. My Data starts from 2017.01 till 2018.04 and I need XAxis to be 2017.01, 2017.02...etc....till 2018.04. Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have not been able to find a clear way to do it. To me, it makes the x-axis unreadable. That is why I suggested only doing 1 year increments.